# Acessar um diretório compartilhado através do PHP, é possível?

Tags: php, windows, redes

Tenho um servidor remoto que possui uma pasta compartilhada ex:

**\servidorremoto\arquivo**

Dentro deste diretório existem diversos arquivos que eu gostaria de checar o tamanho com o PHP.

Dúvida: Com o PHP eu consigo acessar uma pasta compartilhada para esta finalidade?

*Obs: o Servidor destino é um Windows Server e não roda PHP.*

Comment: Ponha o código que tentou, e descreva o problema encontrado, fica mais fácil de quem responder ajudar e ser objetivo.

Comment: Bacco, não tenho código, na verdade eu gostaria de saber se isso é possível! e se sim, alguém saiba alguma função para eu ter uma luz de como fazê-lo!

Comment: É um caminho como qualquer outro, nao tem função diferente pra isso.

Answer (score 4):

### SIM

É possível e está no manual:

> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php

Em especial, o título

**Veja Também: Protocolos e Wrappers suportados**

que "linka" para:

> https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/wrappers.file.php

E o que você busca está aqui:

- `/path/to/file.ext`
- `relative/path/to/file.ext`
- `fileInCwd.ext`
- `C:/path/to/winfile.ext`
- `C:\path\to\winfile.ext`
- **`\\smbserver\share\path\to\winfile.ext`**
- `file:///path/to/file.ext`